# removeEventListener issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-wilbur-6r1c3y?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1366

Can anyone explain why this line is not working?

**"window.removeEventListener("mousemove", tellPos, false);"**

I can see that the function is getting called in the console so I assume its not as easy as it seems to remove event listeners.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [page, setPage] = useState({ pageX: 50, pageY: 50 });
  let [string, setString] = useState(
    "Position X : " + page.pageX + " Position Y : " + page.pageY
  );

  function tellPos(p: any) {
    let page2: any = {};
    page2.pageX = p.pageX - 50;
    page2.pageY = p.pageY - 10;

    setPage(page2);
    setString("Position X : " + p.pageX + " Position Y : " + p.pageY);
  }

  function addListeners() {
    console.log("fire add");
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", tellPos, false);
  }

  function removeListeners() {
    console.log("fire remove");
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", tellPos, false);
  }

  // let style = {position:"absolute", top:page.pageY+"px", left:page.pageX+"px"}

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        removeListeners();
      }}
      className="App"
    >
      <div
        style={{
          border: "1px solid black",
          position: "absolute",
          top: page.pageY + "px",
          left: page.pageX + "px"
        }}
        onMouseEnter={() => {
          addListeners();
        }}
        onClick={() => {
          removeListeners();
        }}
      >
        <h1>hover to move me</h1>
        {string}
      </div>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your code **adds** the same listener function every time the mouse enters the element. The method is called `addEventListener()` for a reason: it adds a listener to the list of already-added listeners, and it does not remove previously-added listener functions.

Comment: the `addListners()` function only runs once from my understanding at least in this situation that is, due to the fact that the mouse never leaves the element.  I am wondering why onClick the `removeListeners()`  function is not removing the listener from the list.

Comment: The real problem is that the whole function `App` seems to be called many times, and so the `tellPos` function that gets removed is not the same anymore as the one that got added. You can verify this by adding a `tellPos.foo = Math.random()` right after the function declaration and then logging it in both addListeners and removeListeners. Otherwise your code would have worked because `EventListener#addEventListener` will add only once the same callback to the same event with the same options. Unfortunately I don't know reactjs enough to help here.

Comment: @Kaiido no, `.addEventListener()` will happily add exactly the same event listener functions to the same element as many times as the code requests it. You can demonstrate this for yourself with an extremely simple test.

Comment: @Pointy yes you can, I invite you to do so. I also invite you to take a 2s read of [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener): "The method addEventListener() works by adding a function, or an object that implements EventListener, to the list of event listeners for the specified event type on the EventTarget on which it's called. **If the function or object is already in the list of event listeners for this target, the function or object is not added a second time.**"

Comment: @Kaiido holy moly, you're right. I guess I've always seen these questions with function expressions, so that each function passed as a listener is a distinct object. It's great to learn stuff like this from Stack Overflow, because on my own I'd never try to re-register a listener, so I would never have encountered this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the problem here:

Upon binding `tellPos` to `mousemove`, you're triggering a re-render (i.e: a re-execution of your `App` function) whenever the mouse is moved (because `tellPos` triggers a state update, which triggers the re-render). Because `tellPos`, `addListeners` and `removeListeners` are defined each time during render, `removeListeners` is being instructed to remove an event handler matching a *new* instance of `tellPos` from `window`, leaving the old one that was bound during the initial `addListeners` intact.

The solution to this problem appears to be avoiding the definition of functions during render, especially when those functions are being bound as event listeners to elements that aren't being replaced in subsequent renders.

I've got a crude demo with `tellPos` stored outside of the render function, showing this functionality seemingly behaving as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-waterfall-xuzlb9?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Looked at the demo and seems to be working as I intended. Will look into the code a bit more. Thanks for the help so far.