# DOM removeEventListener issue

Tags: dom, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I note the following ([Javascript removeEventListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444077/javascript-removeeventlistener-not-working)) I found that details using the same function declaration for both the add and remove event listener calls...
Also, this [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230900/removeeventlistener-issues)

But i dont know that either answer my query..

I am not aware and see no reason for the document to be re-rendered for so presumably there is only a single event listenener bound to my function getCurrentElapsedTime()

However, I still cant get this to work.

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getCurrentElapsedTime,true);`

```
function getCurrentElapsedTime()
{
    ...
}

function eventFinished($eventFinish)
{// user has completed event...
    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getCurrentElapsedTime,true);
}
```

When eventFinished is called.. the listener is still running...

In browser console : `document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',getCurrentElapsedTime,true)`
returns 'undefined'

Help would be appreciated as this has me banging my head against a wall.. thanks in advance

(For the record, ChatGPT also suggests this should work..!)